# how to save date into day, months and years separately in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am designing a database for this shop and they need the application to be able to calculate monthly profit.
My question is that I can retrieve the current date of the system by using the SYSDATE. But this gives me a single value in a single column like 04-JUL-2014.
I want to store the date in three separate columns **DATE, MONTH and YEAR** so that I can simply do a select statement like `select * from <table> where MONTH = MARCH` etc.
If anybody knows how to do this conversion, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is best practice to store a date as a DATE (or TIMESTAMP) data type, and use functions like EXTRACT() and TO_CHAR() to get the various parts of the date.

If you want to have easy-to-write queries for commonly-used reports (like your example based on monthly profit), you can always build views (or materialized views) on the tables. For example:

```
create view Profit_By_Month as
select 
    extract(YEAR from some_date_column) as year, 
    extract(MONTH from some_date_column) as month, 
    sum(profit) as profit 
from sales 
group by 
    extract(YEAR from some_date_column), 
    extract(MONTH from some_date_column)
```

and then you can do this:

```
select year, month, profit from Profit_By_Month order by year, month
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [the `EXTRACT` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions045.htm#i1017161).

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) AS YEAR,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) AS MONTH,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) AS DAY
       FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides an EXTRACT function that will let you query based on components of the date. For example, if you want to add up profits for March, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(profit)
FROM sales
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM sales.date) = 3
```

Storing the date in a DATE column is more flexible than breaking up the components into separate columns because it allows you run queries that you haven't anticipated yet.